# How should I mock atob() function in jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Authorize.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({})
class AuthorizeComponent {
  constructor(private authService: Authservice) {
    this.authService
      .getUserDetails(localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'))
      .subscribe(() => {
        //--my code--
      });
  }
}
```

Auth.Service.ts

```
getUserDetails(token) {
  let userDetails = atob(token);
}
```

Authorize.component.spec.ts

Injected the authService.

```
it("should create", () =>{ 
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
})
```

AuthorizeComponent is not able to create. I am getting

> Error:Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window' :The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Please suggest how should I mock the `atob` function

Comment: You should mock the service

Answer (score 0):

Since the component directly depends on `this.authService.getUserDetails()` method, so this method should be mocked instead of `atob` in this method.

E.g.

`authorize.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({})
export class AuthorizeComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService
      .getUserDetails(localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'))
      .subscribe((v) => {
        //--my code--
        console.log(v);
      });
  }
}
```

`auth.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  getUserDetails(token) {
    let userDetails = atob(token);
    return of(userDetails);
  }
}
```

`authorize.component.spec.ts`:

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthorizeComponent } from './authorize.component';

describe('AuthorizeComponent', () => {
  let component: AuthorizeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuthorizeComponent>;
  let getUserDetailsSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const authService = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthService', ['getUserDetails']);
    getUserDetailsSpy = authService.getUserDetails.and.returnValue(
      of('mocked user')
    );

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AuthorizeComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: AuthService, useValue: authService }],
    });
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    const logSpy = spyOn(console, 'log');
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthorizeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(getUserDetailsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mocked user');
  });
});
```

unit test result:
[image]